# Javascript regex - remove variable from url if exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, query-string, str-replace

I have this url: `http://localhost/example/product/illimani/?lang=fr?lang=fr`

Now I want to remove this `?lang=fr`because this already exists from url.

I hope you understand my question.

If already exists remove `?lang=fr` else don't.

Comment: That gets there from another page, you should find where it originates and use a conditional to check if it would be duplicating before changing pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
url.replace(/(\?lang=fr)+/g, '?lang=fr')
```

To replace multiple occurrences of `?lang=fr` with just one.

Comment: Where I pass my url string?

Comment: This will not replace the string if there is something in between the two occurrences.

Comment: @Aashray - Yeah. I hadn't considered that possibility. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
 var re = /(\?[\w|=]*)+\1/; 
var str = 'http://localhost/example/product/illimani/?lang=fr?lang=fr?lang=fr';

str.match(re);
```

The `re` should be pruned to include URL parameters in a more generalised format. This will only replace consecutive duplicates. If you want to find dis-joint duplicates, then you ought to use a programming language IMHO. You can then replace it with the special code `$1 backreference`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple replace if you just want to handle the one scenario you described:

```
var new_url = url.replace(/(\?lang=fr)+/g, '?lang=fr');
```

To handle all repeated variables, try this instead:

```
var new_url = url;
var temp = '';
while( temp != new_url) { // need this in case params are out of order
    temp = new_url;
    new_url = temp.replace(/([&?])([^=&?]+=[^=&?]+)(.*)\2/g, '$1$2$3');
}
new_url = new_url.replace(/[&?]+/g, '&').replace(/&+/, '?').replace(/&$/, '');
```

For example, this would turn `http://localhost/example/product/illimani/?foo=bar&lang=fr?foo=bar&lang=fr` into `http://localhost/example/product/illimani/?foo=bar&lang=fr`